# QueryString is null # character

Tags: asp.net, query-string

My querystring has next look :

```
   ....xxxx.aspx#access_token=xxxx&expires=xxxx
```

When I chek querystring for values it gives me nothing. In this [Special-Character-sharp-in-URL-Query-String](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/353020/Special-Character-sharp-in-URL-Query-String) article I find that all after # character treats as null.How can I get values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because the values aren't in the query string. They're in the hash, which is only available client-side.

If you want them to be in the query string, you need to use the `?` instead of `#`.

Comment: this mean that I can get values using javascript?I get this string while authorization through application.

Comment: @AntonPutov - You could access the hash in JavaScript using `window.location.hash`.